# java simpledateformat parse string error

Tags: java, simpledateformat

//there is my codes

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "19900416000000";
    String b = "19900415000000";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    df.setLenient(false);

    try {
        df.parse(a);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("a parse error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        df.parse(b);
    }catch (ParseException e){
        System.out.println("b parse error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

// and I get an error,like this

```
b parse error
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at org.suanhua.elasticsearch.client.ETLTest.main(ETLTest.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

So,what's the different between a and b? why parse(b) get an error?

//there is my import

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

// use jdk8 under intellij

Comment: 1990 -- yyyy 04--MM 16--dd 00--HH 00--mm 00--ss

Comment: I did compile with your code. No any error

Comment: Same as kimdung. Ran code. No error. Unable to reproduce.

Comment: there we go http://ideone.com/tRrZRk

Comment: Code works fine for me, maybe you have wrong imports? Try cleaning your project.

Comment: use jdk8 under intellij I get this error

Comment: @Bowie What is your timezone? If your timezone switched to Daylight Savings Time at midnight on 4/15 1990, then the time doesn't exist, and you'd get that error. None of us get the error, because we're in different timezones.

Comment: @Andreas why then String a = "19900416000000"; works for him ?

Comment: @Andreas I changed my codes like this     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);  then I still get an error  ava.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
b parse error

Comment: @AMB Because midnight of 4/16 does exist.

Comment: @Andreas tyvm, i get it now, i didnt know that the clock was set forward to 1 AM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem seems to be timezone related.

Testing all timezones in my jdk1.8.0_91 installation.

```
String a = "19900416000000";
String b = "19900415000000";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
df.setLenient(false);

for (String id : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
    try {
        df.parse(a);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(id + ": " + e);
    }
    try {
        df.parse(b);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(id + ": " + e);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Asia/Chongqing: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
Asia/Chungking: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
Asia/Harbin: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
Asia/Shanghai: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
PRC: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
CTT: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19900415000000"
```

If your default timezone is any of those, then it fails because midnight of April 15, 1990 doesn't exist, as that was the time when Daylight Savings Time started, i.e. at midnight, the clock was set forward to 1 AM, so midnight didn't exist.

Comment: Brilliant, The People's Republic of China experimented with DST from 1986, but abandoned DST from 1992 onwards. The PRC now uses one time zone (UTC+8) for the whole country. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/china/beijing?year=1990

Comment: Thank you very much ! the problem has bothered  me for a long time

Answer (score 1):

[Very well spotted, Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44044998/5772882).

FWIW, Bowie, the newer date and time classes in your JDK 8 can parse the strings and give you for example

```
1990-04-16T00:00+09:00[Asia/Chongqing]
1990-04-15T01:00+09:00[Asia/Chongqing]
```

You will notice the second string has 01 for hours where it said 00 in the input string. I used like (edit: added creation of `dtf`):

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(b, dtf)
                               .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Chongqing")));
```

If you just need the computer’s default time zone, you may use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

In any case, since you are using JDK 8, is there any good reason why you are sticking with the outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and friends? The newer classes are generally much nicer to work with.

If you need to catch the date-time falling in the summer time gap, you will have to handle it specially, though. For example convert back to a `LocalDateTime` and see if you get the same as the one you parsed.

PS I still have an observation I cannot explain satisfactorily: One of the time zones Andreas mentions is CTT. I take this to mean China Taiwan Time, so I had expected it to be the same as Asia/Taipei. However, when I put the latter into my code, I get `1990-04-15T00:00+08:00[Asia/Taipei]`, that is, 00 hours, so here the time 0:00 midnight exists. For the other 5 time zones Andreas mentions I get 01 hours.